# VIM: Is it possible to exit/cancel "colon command" line using just 1 keystroke/shortcut?

Tags: linux, bash, vim

Sometimes I start to search and replace something with `:%s/string/`..., then quickly change my mind. Or, maybe I am manipulating my tabs. I want to quickly return to the cursor position I just left.

Is there a way to cancel that command/go back to the editor using a single shortcut? It's kind of tedious having to just backspace through the command.

Obviously this is very nit picky, but perhaps the answer is simple.

Comment: What about `Ctrl+c` ?

Comment: ...thank you! That's it. Don't know why I never tried that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Ctrl+c


:help CTRL-C

                                                    CTRL-C
CTRL-C              Interrupt current (search) command.  Use CTRL-Break on
                    MS-DOS dos-CTRL-Break.
                    In Normal mode, any pending command is aborted.
```

Comment: Note that if you don't like `Ctrl-c`, `Esc` most likely works as well, but is affected by the `cpoptions` setting.  See `:help c_<Esc>` for more info.

Answer (score 3):

Use <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> to abort the current command.

Answer (score 1):

Just press CTRL+C which will abort the command.

Answer (score 0):

ESC key should also work.
More vimish :)